# SQL - model song collection with multiple genres

Tags: database-design, relational-database

So I'm very new to SQL and I'm trying to model a song collection database as a first project. My entity relationship model would look something like this:

[image: ER-Model]

Now this may work (I think), if every Album and Track only had one Genre it could be associated with. I would then have the following Tables:

```
Tablename: Album
AlbumID, Name, Releaseyear, Genre

Tablename: Artist
ArtistID, Name

Tablename: Track
TrackID, TrackNr, AlbumID, Name, Genre
```

So my question is, if I wanted to have multiple genres would I need to make a separate genre table and how would my already existing tables change or what extra tables would I need?

**edit:**
I updated my ER-model to the suggestion that @EzLo gave me.
The new model looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffqt5.png

The Tables I would end up with are now:

```
Tablename: Album
AlbumID, ArtistID(foreign key) Name, Releaseyear

Tablename: Artist
ArtistID, Name

Tablename: Track
SongID, TrackNr, AlbumID(forgot to draw in ER-model), Name

Tablename: Genre
GenreID, Name

Tablename: GenreByAlbum
GenreID(foreign key), AlbumID(foreign key)

Tablename: GenreByTrack
GenreID(foreign key), SongID(foreign key)
```

Does this modelling approach work or am I missing something? I know that a Track can have more than one artist, however I want model it so that a track only shows one artist for simplicity reasons.

Comment: An album can be related to many Genres and a Genre can be related to many different albums, this is what is called an N to M (many to many) relationship and it's modeled with 3 tables: Genre, Album and GenreByAlbum which links a particular Genre with a particular Album. This GenreByAlbum table has to have a primary key that's composed of 2 foreign keys: one for Genre and another for Album.

Comment: You need quite a few suggestions, I think.  The track table should have either one or more artists associated with it, because each track may have one or more contributors.

Comment: The use of a join or bridge table between the Genre/Album and Genre/Track tables is correct. I would not however call it GenreByAlbum because that implies an order of importance between Genre and Album, where actually none exists. Its a junction of Album and Genre, and should just be called "GenreAlbum" or "AlbumGenre". I will however concede this is nitpicking!